# Eval format in textbox

Tags: html, asp.net, web

I have been trying to apply Eval on textbox which its mode is `TextMode="Date"`. The date is not loading in to the text box and this is because the textmode. It seems to be that the Eval format is not working at all. When I remove the textmode it works. I have been trying several on variations and non of them have worked.

Here is some of them:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="birthdayTB" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Birthday")).ToString("d")  %>'  TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="birthdayTB" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Birthday", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")  %>'  TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="birthdayTB" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Birthday", "{0:d}")  %>'  TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I make this work? 
Thank you.

Comment: Does the formatting work if you remove the Textmode?

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail, "not working at all" is not meaningful at all. What is the result? A runtime exception, the wrong format?

Comment: Sorry. Serv - if I remove the textmode it works.   Tim Schmelter - I meant that the data is not loading in to the text box. all I can see is the default text of `textmode = date` which is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Have you tried the solution posted here: http://forums.asp.net/post/5724683.aspx ? This seems to excactly match your problem. Like the other search results on codeProject this hints, that the issue might be browser related und you should be better off using a Javascript library to extend datepicker functionality

Answer (score 0):

Use on **code behind**

```
birthdayTB.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Birthday).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```